# Guice Dependency Injection between different projects

Tags: java, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

Initially I started working on a Play! Java project that has a `Controller`, `Processor` and `DAO`. I used dependency injection using Google Guice's `@ImplementedBy` for my `Processor` interface and my `ProcessorImpl` implemented it.

Right now, I have created another project which also requires the `Processor`. So I extracted out the interface to another separate project, say **common**, and the two projects use that common project as a referenced library.

The problem is, I won't be able to use `@ImplementedBy` anymore since that common project will not have the two projects' references. Since that is not possible, I am not able to go for dependency injection. Without giving `@ImplementedBy`, I am getting the following error:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for com.processor.Processor was bound.
```

Is there a way to configure the dependencies in a config file? Or can the dependency be injected in the implemented classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a guice module in project where your ProcessorImpl is located.

```
public class Module extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure() {
         bind(Processor.class).to(ProcessorImpl.class);
    }
}
```

Inject Processor wherever you need.

If you call this module Module and place it in the root package, it will automatically be registered with Play.

Comment: I have created this module too. But what do you mean by root package? I created my own package and placed it inside that package. Also, I have used `@Override` on top of the function.

Comment: If you have already placed it in your package, check if you have added  **play.modules.enabled += "modules.Module"** in your **application.conf** file.